# UIView screenshot with magnificationFilter

Tags: ios

I have a tiny qrcode UIImage set to a large UIImageView. In order to avoid any gradient from black to white when amplifying, I setted the UIImageView magnification filter to kCAFilterNearest as shown below (it works):

```
[QRCodeImageView layer].magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
```

Now I need to take a screenshot from this ImageView, but the result image is ignoring the magnification filter:

[image: Screenshot Issue]

Here is my screenshot code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(QRCodeImageView.frame.size.width, QRCodeImageView.frame.size.height),YES, 2.0f);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[QRCodeImageView.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So, the question is, how to render in context with a given magnification filter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you check out this question. The answer has not been selected, but worth a try nevertheless http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541352/kcafilternearest-maginifcation-filter-uiimageview

Comment: I'm having this problem too... the basis for it seems to be this quote from the documentation on `renderInContext`: "Important: The OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not support the entire Core Animation composition model. QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not rendered, nor are layers that specify backgroundFilters, filters, compositingFilter, or a mask values. Future versions of OS X may add support for rendering these layers and properties." Have yet to find a solution, unfortunately.